# сборка и запуск проекта на AstraLinux

Tags: c++, debian, ssh, astra-linux, visual-studio-2019

Возникает ошибка при сборке проекта на AstraLinux.

"Произошла ошибка. Could not start the 'rsync' command on the remote host, please install it using your system package manager. Please see ..."

При этом всё необходимое есть на машине.
[image]

Устанавливал всё по MSDN-новским гайдам: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/get-started-linux-cmake?view=vs-2019
и https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/linux/configure-a-linux-project?view=vs-2019.

Всё что в них указано поставить, всё поставлено:
[image]

При сборке проекта, он крашиться на моменте: "При копировании исходных файлов на удаленный компьютер возникло исключение: Could not create directories, mkdir exit code: 1".

Всё что описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389483/visual-studio-2017-could-not-create-directories-mkdir-exit-code-1) опробовал, НЕ помогло.

Есть идеи, как их можно побороть и из первой ошибки может выходить вторая или они не взаимосвязаны?

P.S. Журнал: "liblinux.IO.RemoteRsyncDaemon: Config directory creation failed with output:  and error output: Could not chdir to home directory /home/astra: Permission denied
bash: /home/astra/.bashrc: Отказано в доступе" - нужны права суперпользователя?

Comment: Первый скрин, нет?

Comment: Всю текстовую информацию следует передавать тектом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так написано же - недостаточно прав. Дайте соответствующие права. Разберитесь с мандатным контролем целостности, проверьте что уровень целостности пользователя высокий (63).

Comment: Пытаюсь создать нового пользователя под рутом и система мне не позволяет этого сделать.

"root@astra: sudo useradd petuch -m -G root
root@astra: не удалось создать каталог /home/petuch"

Без каталога я могу добавлять пользователей, но оно мне и не надо без каталога. В этом вся проблема, что я не могу под рутом добавлять домашние каталоги пользователям. Хотя поидее у него все права есть